# increment and addition operators precedence, cpp

Tags: c++, operator-precedence

I have 2 questions.

consider this code:

```
int x=1,y=2;
int z =(x++)+(++y);
int w = (++x)++;
cout << z << "\t" << w << "\t" << x;
```

Now, this gives me 4, 3 and 4 and I'm guessing that `w=3`is because this `int w = (++x)++` is undefined behavior, and that's fine with me. What I don't understand is this: I tried to write this line `int w = (++x)++;` like this `int w = ++x++;` and got `error: lvalue required as increment operand`, but, I saw [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) that postfix takes precedence over prefix, so why the isn't the postfix increment done, returns the variable and then increments it with the prefix? (as it is done when I use bracket)

Now back to this line: `int z =(x++)+(++y)`. I tried to write it like `int z =x+++++y` and that didn't work - same error. Then I tried `int z =x+++(++y)` and it was fine, so what I think happened is this:

1. x++
2. ++y
3. addition

but if I'm correct, why the brackets were needed? this is the way it should be by precedence

Comment: .. and why are you doing this?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath for better understanding

Comment: There is nothing much to understand here, just PLEASE don't ever do this!

Comment: The "maximal munch" tokenisation rule makes `x+++++y` into `((x++)++) + y`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> so why the isn't the postfix increment done, returns the variable

The postfix version doesn't return a reference, it returns a value - and the prefix increment can only work with a reference.

By adding brackets, you've changed the order of evaluation.

Answer (score -2):

It is not an issue of precedence, but the way compiler parses the code.
To compile correctly you don't need to use brackets. Will work fine with spaces.

Comment: Tried compiling it without brackets and got errors (int w = ++x ++; -> gave an error)

Comment: @CIsForCookies Did you try adding spaces between the operators? `z = x++ + ++x;`?

Comment: @Barmar the line you suggested works fine with spaces. The line I mentioned in the previous comment doesn't